# Jupyterhub fail to show the cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

When I lunched the python3 notebook in JupyterHub, waited for long time and then only show the logo of JupyterHub and the menu toolbars without showing any cells (there are many cells in the notebook). I have shut-downed any other notebook on the hub, and also tried shutdown-restart this notebook many times, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for the jupyterhub server logs. You can share the log details here. Please mask any credentials in the logs before sharing it here.